# Unable to install wine on Linux Mint 16

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, wine

In my work's intranet there is a local ubuntu repo and wine ppa.

**sources.list**:

```
deb http://***<myintranet>***/ubuntu/ saucy main multiverse restricted universe 
deb http://***/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main multiverse restricted universe 
deb http://***/ubuntu/ saucy-security main multiverse restricted universe 
deb http://***/ubuntu/ saucy-backports main multiverse restricted universe 

deb http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine lucid main
deb http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine precise main
deb http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine quantal main
deb http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine raring main
```

Now when I do `sudo apt-get install wine` I got this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
                 wine1.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I don't know why is this happening, my coworkers are using the same configuration with ubuntu 13.10 and are just fine. And with this configuration in linux mint 15 I was able to install wine without problems.

Any suggestions? Maybe I must install something first?

I've also tried `sudo apt-get install wine1.7`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-amd64 (= 1:1.7.13-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.13-0ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**EDIT:**

This is how I have my sources now:

```
deb http://***/ubuntu saucy main multiverse restricted universe
deb http://***/ubuntu saucy-updates main multiverse restricted universe
deb http://***/ubuntu saucy-security main multiverse restricted universe
deb http://***/ubuntu saucy-backports main multiverse restricted universe
```

And this is `/etc/apt/`:

[image]

Output of `apt-cache madison ^wine`:

```
winefish | 1.3.3-0dl1ubuntu2 | http://***/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
wine1.4-amd64 | 1.4.1-0ubuntu7 | http://***/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
      wine | 1.4.1-0ubuntu7 | http://***/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
winetricks | 0.0+20130702+svn1032-1 | http://***/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
   wine1.4 | 1.4.1-0ubuntu7 | http://***/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
wine-gecko1.4 | 1.4.0-0ubuntu2 | http://***/ubuntu/ saucy/multiverse amd64 Packages
wine1.4-dbg | 1.4.1-0ubuntu7 | http://***/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
wine1.4-dev | 1.4.1-0ubuntu7 | http://***/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
```

Note that now I only have access to `wine1.4` which is in the ubuntu repo. If I add the ppa again this is the ouput of `apt-cache madison ^wine`:

```
winefish | 1.3.3-0dl1ubuntu2 | http://***/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
wine1.5-dbg | 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
wine1.5-dbg | 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
wine1.5-dbg | 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ raring/main amd64 Packages
wine1.5-dev | 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
wine1.5-dev | 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
wine1.5-dev | 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ raring/main amd64 Packages
wine-mono4.5.0 | 4.5.0-0ubuntu1~ppa1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
wine-mono4.5.0 | 4.5.0-0ubuntu1~ppa1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
wine-mono4.5.0 | 4.5.0-0ubuntu1~ppa1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ raring/main amd64 Packages
wine-mono4.5.2 | 4.5.2-0ubuntu1~ppa1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
wine-mono4.5.2 | 4.5.2-0ubuntu1~ppa1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
wine-mono4.5.2 | 4.5.2-0ubuntu1~ppa1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ raring/main amd64 Packages
wine1.6-dbg | 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
wine1.6-dbg | 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
wine1.6-dbg | 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ raring/main amd64 Packages
wine1.4-amd64 | 1.4.1-0ubuntu7 | http://***/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
wine1.4-amd64 | 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa4 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
wine1.4-amd64 | 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa4 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
wine1.6-dev | 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
wine1.6-dev | 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
wine1.6-dev | 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ raring/main amd64 Packages
      wine | 1:1.7.13-0ubuntu1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
      wine | 1:1.7.13-0ubuntu1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
      wine | 1:1.7.13-0ubuntu1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ raring/main amd64 Packages
      wine | 1.4.1-0ubuntu7 | http://***/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
      wine | 1.2.3-0ubuntu1~ppa2~lucid1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ lucid/main amd64 Packages
wine1.5-amd64 | 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
wine1.5-amd64 | 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
wine1.5-amd64 | 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ raring/main amd64 Packages
wine1.3-gecko |    1.4.0+1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ lucid/main amd64 Packages
winetricks | 0.0+20130707~precise1~ppa1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
winetricks | 0.0+20130707~precise1~ppa1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
winetricks | 0.0+20130707~precise1~ppa1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ raring/main amd64 Packages
winetricks | 0.0+20130702+svn1032-1 | http://***/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
winetricks | 0.0+20120308~ppa1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ lucid/main amd64 Packages
wine1.7-dbg | 1:1.7.13-0ubuntu1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
wine1.7-dbg | 1:1.7.13-0ubuntu1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
wine1.7-dbg | 1:1.7.13-0ubuntu1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ raring/main amd64 Packages
wine1.7-dev | 1:1.7.13-0ubuntu1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
wine1.7-dev | 1:1.7.13-0ubuntu1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
wine1.7-dev | 1:1.7.13-0ubuntu1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ raring/main amd64 Packages
wine-mono0.0.4 | 0.0.4-0ubuntu1~ppa1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
wine-mono0.0.4 | 0.0.4-0ubuntu1~ppa1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
wine-mono0.0.8 | 0.0.8-0ubuntu1~ppa2 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
wine-mono0.0.8 | 0.0.8-0ubuntu1~ppa2 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
wine-mono0.0.8 | 0.0.8-0ubuntu1~ppa2 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ raring/main amd64 Packages
wine1.6-amd64 | 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
wine1.6-amd64 | 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
wine1.6-amd64 | 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ raring/main amd64 Packages
  wine-dev | 1.2.2-1ubuntu1~lucid1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ lucid/main amd64 Packages
wine1.2-dbg | 1.2.3-0ubuntu1~ppa2~lucid1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ lucid/main amd64 Packages
wine-gecko2.21 | 2.21-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
wine-gecko2.21 | 2.21-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
wine-gecko2.21 | 2.21-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ raring/main amd64 Packages
wine-gecko2.24 | 2.24-0ubuntu1~ppa1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
wine-gecko2.24 | 2.24-0ubuntu1~ppa1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
wine-gecko2.24 | 2.24-0ubuntu1~ppa1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ raring/main amd64 Packages
wine1.7-amd64 | 1:1.7.13-0ubuntu1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
wine1.7-amd64 | 1:1.7.13-0ubuntu1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
wine1.7-amd64 | 1:1.7.13-0ubuntu1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ raring/main amd64 Packages
wine1.2-dev | 1.2.3-0ubuntu1~ppa2~lucid1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ lucid/main amd64 Packages
   wine1.2 | 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa4 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
   wine1.2 | 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa4 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
   wine1.2 | 1.2.3-0ubuntu1~ppa2~lucid1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ lucid/main amd64 Packages
   wine1.3 | 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa4 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
   wine1.3 | 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa4 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
   wine1.3 | 1.4-0ubuntu1~ppa1~lucid1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ lucid/main amd64 Packages
   wine1.4 | 1.4.1-0ubuntu7 | http://***/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
   wine1.4 | 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa4 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
   wine1.4 | 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa4 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
   wine1.5 | 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
   wine1.5 | 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
   wine1.5 | 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ raring/main amd64 Packages
   wine1.6 | 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
   wine1.6 | 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
   wine1.6 | 1:1.6.1-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ raring/main amd64 Packages
   wine1.7 | 1:1.7.13-0ubuntu1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
   wine1.7 | 1:1.7.13-0ubuntu1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
   wine1.7 | 1:1.7.13-0ubuntu1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ raring/main amd64 Packages
wine1.3-dbg | 1.4-0ubuntu1~ppa1~lucid1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ lucid/main amd64 Packages
wine-gecko | 1.2.2-1ubuntu1~lucid1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ lucid/main amd64 Packages
wine1.3-dev | 1.4-0ubuntu1~ppa1~lucid1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ lucid/main amd64 Packages
wine-gecko1.4 | 1.4.0-0ubuntu2 | http://***/ubuntu/ saucy/multiverse amd64 Packages
wine-gecko1.5 | 1.5-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
wine-gecko1.6 | 1.6-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
wine-gecko1.7 | 1.7-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
wine-gecko1.7 | 1.7-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
wine-gecko1.8 | 1.8-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
wine-gecko1.8 | 1.8-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
wine-gecko1.8 | 1.8-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ raring/main amd64 Packages
wine-gecko1.9 | 1.9-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
wine-gecko1.9 | 1.9-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
wine-gecko1.9 | 1.9-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ raring/main amd64 Packages
wine1.4-dbg | 1.4.1-0ubuntu7 | http://***/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
wine1.4-dbg | 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa4 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
wine1.4-dbg | 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa4 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
wine1.4-common | 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa4 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
wine1.4-common | 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa4 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
wine1.4-dev | 1.4.1-0ubuntu7 | http://***/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
wine1.4-dev | 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa4 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ precise/main amd64 Packages
wine1.4-dev | 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa4 | http://***/ubuntu-ppa/wine/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
```

**EDIT 2:**

After setting the sources to the saucy repo:

```
deb http://***/ubuntu saucy main multiverse restricted universe
deb http://***/ubuntu saucy-updates main multiverse restricted universe
deb http://***/ubuntu saucy-security main multiverse restricted universe
deb http://***/ubuntu saucy-backports main multiverse restricted universe
```

This is the ouput of `apt-get install wine`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.4 but it is not going to be installed
 wine1.4-amd64 : Depends: libgphoto2-2 (>= 2.4.10.1) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libgphoto2-port0 (>= 2.4.10.1) but it is not installable
 wine1.4-common : Depends: wine1.4 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu1~precise1~ppa4) but it is not going to be installed
 wine1.4-i386:i386 : Depends: libgphoto2-2:i386 (>= 2.4.10.1) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libgphoto2-port0:i386 (>= 2.4.10.1) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: That's not your entire sources.list is it? You seem to also be using Mint's `incoming` repo. You also have 4 different Ubuntu distros in your list, that can also cause this problem depending on the way you've set it up. By the way, are you sure this is Mint and not Mint Debian? AFAIK, Incoming is an LMDE thing

Comment: I'm using Mint 16 Cinnamon amd64. And yes I've copy pasted all the distros of the wine ppa as a last resource cause trying with just the saucy repo was not working (But it is working for the ubuntu users). And about the `incoming` repo how could I disable it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache madison ^wine`, and make sure you remove all other versions from your sources, you should only use the ones that correspond to the version you're on. Finally, please post the entire `/etc/apt/sources.list` as well as any files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Comment: @terdon I've added requested info

Comment: OK, each time you make a change to your sources, you need to run `sudo apt-get update` for those changes to take effect. The output of `apt-cache madison` shows that you haven't since it lists stuff from the repos you have deleted. Make sure you run that command _before_ running the `apt-cache`. Also, you are showing the contents of the `/apt/` directory but I asked for the content of any _files_ in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` since they will be appended to the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: Ok, I know how to use `apt-get update`, the second output I've showed is after I modified the sources to put back the wine ppas to show the ouput of `apt-cache madison ^wine` (with the intermediate calls to `apt-get update`). I mean: the first output is how I have the configuration **now** and the second was to show the ppas (previous conf). Also I post the image because `/sources.list.d` **is empty** as you can check (0 items). Hope it helps

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13291/discussion-between-terdon-and-xndrme)

Comment: @terdon I'm trying to enter the chat but the conection is reaaaally slooowww, please wait and thanks for your help anyways :)

Comment: OK, in the meantime, please run the `apt-cache` command again but with only a single ppa added to your sources, the one that corresponds to the Ubuntu version your mint is based on.

Comment: @terdon I can't do that because my Mint version is based on Saucy but the ppas are for `lucid` `precise` `quantal` and `raring`, Should I try with `raring`?

Comment: That's probably the problem right there, there will be different versions of various libraries and those will cause dependency problems. The ppas assume that you have access to the correct versions and your system does not. Your friends are probably running one of the supported Ubuntu versions.

Comment: NO, they are using just the default wine (1.4) from the saucy repo (see the first output of `apt-cache madison ^wine`), I try with that but nothing. I will post the output of this try.

Comment: OK, I'm confused, if you don't need the specific version of wine, why don't you just remove the PPAs and install the one from your distro's repositories? You will always have issues trying to install packages from different versions into your system.

Comment: Because The one on the repo doesn't install either, see the last edit of my question! It seem that `libgphoto2-2` is missing on the repo, maybe there is no solution :(

Comment: Yes, because you also need the official Mint and Ubuntu repos which you don't seem to have (at least I can't see them in your Q). Your sources file should also include this: http://hajimu.org/?p=3590

Comment: what about an install through `dpkg` and just raw `deb` package instead of all this?